# How Mirror webpages as Web Video Wall into another browser?

Tags: web, browser

We have a video wall with some monitors. each one is plugged into a Raspberry PI 3.

Mostly we just are showing webpages into the video wall (reports, status etc) 
Today we control the content of each raspberry using VNC. I was wondering if is there a web service or plugin that allows me to just configure the URL that I wish to show on each screen. Plus, Sometimes we split the each screen into 2 or more webpages.

Is there any web app, chrome plugin or web service that allows me do that?

Thanks

OBS, I don't know if here is the right place to this kind of question. If is there another community where i could ask this, i will be glad to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not give a complete and exhaustive answer, since you do not provide any description of how it should look and how you want to control it.

Let's start with the fact that almost every browser at startup you can specify URL and start the browser like this:

```
# firefox https://google.com
```

Then the browser opens with the page you need.

To close the page, you can kill the browser with a command like this

```
# killall firefox
```

You can run commands on the Raspberry PI using ssh, it's much easier than running the VNC session.

Most likely you may encounter a problem when you receive a message stating that the browser can not connect to the display. This is easily correctable with something like:

```
# export DISPLAY=:0
```

In order for the browser to always be in full-screen mode and not to lose its settings, you can configure it correctly, close all the tabs and save its configuration from `~/.mozilla/` (for firefox), and then restore it from backup every time you start it.